# How to transfer push tokens from mainnet to goerli?

Tags: tokens, transfer

I swapped my Eth in mainnet to get push tokens in Mainnet. I need to use these tokens to create a channel in staging app of PushProtocol. However, when I switch to Goerli network on Metamask on which the staging (not production) app runs for PushProtocol, I do not see the tokens. I could not find a way to swap Goerli ETH to PushProtocol tokens or ay other way to purchase on this network. How should I progress?

In order to create a channel I need to have these tokens.

Please help..

Kind Regards,
Ferda

Answer (score 1):

You won't see your **mainnet** tokens on the **Goerli testnet** because these are two **distinct** networks with separate ledgers. Tokens acquired on one network don't automatically transfer to another. If you need PushProtocol tokens on the **Goerli** network, you usually acquire these through a faucet or by directly interacting with the project's **Goerli** contract, in this case PushProtocol

You'll need some **Goerli ETH** for transaction fees too, which you can generally acquire from a Goerli faucet.

Best regards, **X**

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer given by @frostX.eth. Here is the way to get push tokens on goerli.

Head over to this contract - https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x2b9bE9259a4F5Ba6344c1b1c07911539642a2D33

**1. Click on contract**-

[image]

**2. Click on Write Contract-**

[image]

**3. Click on mint and enter the amount and then click on write, you'll get the tokens.**

[image]